# Backbone.js Pinterest modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, pinterest

i'm using backbone.js to build my frontend. 
So what i want to do is, to render a view in a "lightbox" (the same way like pinterest). 
I tried it that way:

```
var itemDetailsBoxView = CloseableView.extend({
el: '#itemwrapperItemBox #itemwrapperItem2',
initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;
    self.render(options);
},
render: function(options) {
    $('#itemwrapperItemBox').fadeIn(300);
    var self = this;
    app._itemDetailsView = new itemDetailsView({id: options.id, el: '#itemwrapperItemBox #itemwrapperItem2'});
    self.rendered(app._itemDetailsView);
},
events: {
    'keydown': 'keydownHandler'
},
keydownHandler: function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        // esc
        case 27 :
            $('#itemwrapperItemBox').hide();
            break;

    }
}
```

This view just opens another view (itemDetailsView) in a lightbox. This itemDetailsBoxView is opened when i click on an item:

```
 itemDetails: function(events) {
    var self = this;
    var that = $(events.currentTarget).parents('.item');
    var id = that.find('.covercontainer').find('img').data('id');
    if (app._itemDetailsBox) {
        app._itemDetailsBox.close();
    }
    app._itemDetailsBox = new itemDetailsBoxView({id: id});
    self.rendered(app._itemDetailsBox);
    app.navigate("/collage/" + id, false);
},
```

However, there are several problems with this approach:

1. When the itemWrapperItem2 appears (like a pin on Pinterest when you zoom in), there are two scrollbars. One for the itemStream in the background and one for the lightbox.
2. The itemDetailsView generates also an itemStream. When i click there on an item, it loads again in the itemDetailsBoxView and also pushes the url (Same functionality, when u have a pin open and click again on a pin). This means, that when i want to go back to the original itemStream, i have a problem because i don't know the URL.

There are more - but this is enough to see, that this approach doesn't work to good. So do you know a solution for backbone.js to copy the whole pinterest "zoom in on a pin" functionality (including, that you land on another page when you reload the pin).

This is my first post here - please be gentle if this post has to less description :)